# How to remove string between two words

Tags: c#, javascript, html, regex

I am downloading web pages using below lines of code,

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(strURL);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();

string html = String.Empty;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
{
  html = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

then from here I am extracting body part as below:

```
int nBodyStart = downloadString.IndexOf("<body");
int nBodyEnd = downloadString.LastIndexOf("</body>");
String strBody = downloadString.Substring(nBodyStart, (nBodyEnd - nBodyStart + 7));
```

Now I want to remove any javascript attached in the body part, How can I do that?

My aim to get the only contents of the web page. But as each page may have different approach, so I am trying to remove any js tags and then remove any HTML tags using below RegEx

```
Regex.Replace(strBody, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", "").Trim();
```

But I don't know how to remove js between script tags as the script may be multi-line or single line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any time regex parsing of html comes up....this post always worth a read  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @GrantWinney I tried using that. But even though my URL is of 242 characters, it throws below exception:

The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match script tags (including the inside of the pair), use the following:

`<script[^>]*>(.*?)</script>`

To match all HTML tags (but not the inside of the pair) you can use:

`</?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>`

---

I just realised you might also want to remove style tags too:

`<style[^>]*>(.*?)</style>`

---

Full regular expression string here:

`<script[^>]*>(.*?)</script>|<style[^>]*>(.*?)</style>|</?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>|<[^>]+>|&nbsp;`

Comment: the regex you provided removes only tags that too from single line only. What if the start and end of script tags are on different line? Also I want to remove the contents in between them.

Comment: If you are matching with javascript, you may have to specify `[\r\n]` with any 'dot' matches. If you are using C#, it might be the same, or you can specify that dot matches newline with `(?s)` at the beginning of the regular expression.

Comment: You got me closer. But its not removing the contents between script tags. I don't contents between script tags as well. And I am coding in C#.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to do this in C#, but I have a feeling that dot does not match newline by default. In regex, you specify the mode with `(?s)` like this: `(?s)(?:<(?:script|style)[^>]*>(.*?)</(?:script|style)>|</?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>)`, but if there is some part of C# that overrides it, it will not work. For example, if the function which performs the match itself will only read single lines, you'll have to use a different function.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I ended up using your old reg ex with little modifications. So final Reg-ex is as follows
'<script[^>]*>(.*?)</script>|<style[^>]*>(.*?)</style>|</?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>|<[^>]+>|&nbsp;'

Answer (score 1):

you can use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(strURL);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();

string html = String.Empty;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
{
  html = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);

// to remove all tags 
var result = document.DocumentNode.InnerText;

// to remove script tags inside body 
document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body").Descendants()
                .Where(n => n.Name == "script")
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(n => n.Remove());
```

Comment: He wants to remove all tags (as in `<whatever>`) as well and just keep the text. At least that's what I understood.

Comment: I tried using that. But even though my URL is of 242 characters, it throws below exception: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Comment: @juan.facorro You are right. I want to remove all the tags. I just want to keep main data/content of the body. Not js functions, images or any extra things apart from content.

Comment: @PratikGaikwad You already have download html as string, you can use that one and also if you want to remove all the tags use `document.DocumentNode.InnerText`

Comment: @Damith: I tried that as well, got again an exception : An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Illegal characters in path.